# SQL Server 2005 Maintenance Plan fails

Tags: sql-server-2005

I am getting an error on our Maintenance plan in sql server 2005 saying that the Setp1 of job cannot be run because the SSIS subsystem failted to load.  The job has been suspended.  How can I fix this and unsuspend the job so that I can run the plan?

Answer (score 0):

You might want use this script from  [Ola Hallengren](http://ola.hallengren.com/).
Or you might want to shell out for RedGate SQL Backup

Either way you'll be in safe hands